# Does Bibtex *require* linebreaks?

Tags: bibtex

this is a bit of an implementation question. Every example I have seen about BibTex looks like this:

```
@book{ab94,
   author* = {Charalambos D. Aliprantis and Kim C. Border},
   year = {1994},
   title = {Infinite Dimensional Analysis},
   publisher = {Springer},
   address = {Berlin}
}
```

Will BibTex parsers also generally be fine with no line breaks, like this?

```
@book{ab94,author* = {Charalambos D. Aliprantis and Kim C. Border}, year = {1994},title = {Infinite Dimensional Analysis},publisher = {Springer},address = {Berlin}}
```

Or will removing the linebreaks mess up how other programs open the bibtex files?

Note: I did spend more than 20 minutes searching, including looking at this page. http://www.bibtex.org/Format/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. We generally like questions to include an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as it makes the whole process of answering much more efficient.

Comment: parsers do not care as long as the structure is correct.